# how to find all occurrence of special characters in a file and add them to a python list

Tags: python

I want to read a text file and append all occurrence of special characters like  (,),{,},[,] in the order in which they appear, how do I do this ?

Comment: what did you try so far?

Comment: can you give a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) about what you want to do? or the code that you have tried so far?

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.  Stack Overflow is not a free code-writing service.  Write some code and ask a question here about a problem that you have with your code.

Comment: result2 = []
    for lines in myfile:
        x = lines.find("(")
        if x != -1:
           result2.append("(")
    print result2

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Note: This code will not work. You will need to open the correct file and have a list of special chars but it should give you an idea of how to start.

```
list = []
f = open('file', 'r')
for line in f:
   for char in line:
       if (char in listOfSpecialChars):
           list.append(char)
```

Comment: list = []
special = ['(',')','[',']','{','}']
for liness in myfile:
   for char in liness:
       if (char in special):
           list.append(char)
print list

Comment: Thanks NendoTaka , it worked

Comment: Please make sure to choose an answer to the question if it is answered so that people know the question is solved.